# Scrollable Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my tablet application I want to create a fragment that displays information based on a list fragment click, the fragment has different tabs that I want to scroll between with a view pager. But the problem is that you can't do a fragment in a fragment so how can I achieve what I want to do or is it even possible to do what I want?

basically I have a persistant list fragment on he left, choosing an item shows some sort of view that I can scroll between tabs. I am trying to avoid creating a whole separate activity since I do a lot based on this list view click in this activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then the only structure that comes to my mind is to use the ViewPager as the highest level and put the listadapter on the left side of each view, switching between the views by pressing on an item in the listView.

Just create one common xml base file and include the specifics for each view in the xml file for each view.  This way you can have a hierachy in the xml file that makes development easier